# invalid Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in controller

Tags: codeigniter

i have problem with Invalid argument supplied for foreach();
so here my controller:

```
public function insertsebab(){


    foreach($this->input->post('id_konsultasi') as $se) 
    {

        $data = array(
        'id_konsultasi'     =>$se,
        'kd_sebab'      => $this->input->post('kd_sebab')  
             );

        $konsultasi = $this->class_model->insertsebab($data);
        $json =$konsultasi;

        echo json_encode($json);

    }

}
```

where is wrong code,how to resolve it?

Comment: I don't think if '$this->input->post('id_konsultasi')' is an array.

Comment: check exactly what is in your $this->input->post('id_konsultasi') first. print_r($this->input->post('id_konsultasi')); I think blank argument or non array argument is coming with your $this->input->post('id_konsultasi').

Comment: data is null when i try in web,but in postman data show after input

Comment: can you share debug output of  $this->input->post('id_konsultasi') like var_dump($this->input->post('id_konsultasi')); so that we can see the data you are dealing with ?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public function insertsebab()
{

    if (is_array($this->input->post('id_konsultasi')) || is_object($this->input->post('id_konsultasi'))) {
        foreach ($this->input->post('id_konsultasi') as $se) {

            $data = array(
                'id_konsultasi' => $se,
                'kd_sebab' => $this->input->post('kd_sebab')
            );

            $konsultasi = $this->class_model->insertsebab($data);
            $json = $konsultasi;

            echo json_encode($json);

        }
    }else{
        //do something if condition is not satisfied or null data
    }
}
```

what I have done is check if your `$this->input->post('id_konsultasi')` is array or object, so when `$this->input->post('id_konsultasi')` is empty it will not return any error

Answer (score 0):

First you need to assign post data in a variable and after that you need check it is a array and not empty

```
public function insertsebab()
{
    $kd_sebab = $this->input->post('kd_sebab');
    $var = $this->input->post('id_konsultasi');
    if (is_array($var) &&  !empty($var) {
        foreach ($var as $se) {

            $data = array(
                'id_konsultasi' => $se,
                'kd_sebab' => $kd_sebab
            );

            $konsultasi = $this->class_model->insertsebab($data);
            $json = $konsultasi;

            echo json_encode($json);

        }
    }else{
        //do something if condition is not satisfied or null data
    }
}
```